# C# to SQL Server SqlBulkCopy large row count

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I'm running a process on a large file of CSV data that's being parsed in to an object graph like this ...

```
Company
 - Address
 -  References [] 
     - Ref 1
```

It's a custom parser that does a line by line parse of the data from the source file which is about 2GB.

The net result is that the object is split up in to 3 different batches and given to the SqlBulkCopy class for insertion in to Sql.

Over time Sql is slowing down until eventually it times out.

I can increase the timeout but all that's going to do is push the exception back and take longer to reach ... ultimately though it'll still be hit, just further down the process.

Is there way to enforce a constant performance rule or something on the connection / on SqlBulkCopy / in Sql Server somehow that gives me some sort of "fixed response time" since all my batches are of a known fixed sized and the operation is simply a repeat of the same op just with more data?

I'm expecting a total row count of about 60 million rows for entire operation.

Here's how i'm doing it ...

```cs
using (var parser = new MappedCSVParser<Company>(config, map, new BufferedStream(File.Open(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))))
{
    var data = parser.Parse();

    Company[] companies = data.Take(batchSize).Where(c => c.IsActive).ToArray();
    Address[] addresses = companies.Select(c => c.Address).ToArray();
    CompanyReference[] refs = companies.SelectMany(c => c.References).ToArray();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (var addCopier = new SqlBulkCopier<Address>(conn))
        using (var comCopier = new SqlBulkCopier<Company>(conn))
        using (var refCopier = new SqlBulkCopier<CompanyReference>(conn))
        {
            var addressReader = new ObjectDataReader<Address>();
            var companyReader = new ObjectDataReader<Company>();
            var refReader = new ObjectDataReader<CompanyReference>();

            await conn.OpenAsync();

            while (companies.Any())
            {
                addressReader.SetSource(addresses);
                companyReader.SetSource(companies);
                refReader.SetSource(refs);

                await addCopier.WriteToServer(addressReader);
                await comCopier.WriteToServer(companyReader);
                await refCopier.WriteToServer(refReader);

                batchesSent++;
                companiesSent += companies.Length;
                rejections += batchSize - companies.Length;
                Log($"Progress - Batches Sent: {batchesSent}, Companies Sent: {companiesSent}, Rejected: {rejections}");

                companies = data.Take(batchSize).Where(c => c.IsActive).ToArray();
                addresses = companies.Select(c => c.Address).ToArray();
                refs = companies.SelectMany(c => c.References).ToArray();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As requested here is my SqlBulkCopy implementation ...

```cs
class SqlBulkCopier<T> : IDisposable
{
    SqlBulkCopy copier;
    SqlConnection connection;
    bool internalConnection = false;

    public SqlBulkCopier(string connStr) : this(new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        internalConnection = true;
    }

    public SqlBulkCopier(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        connection = conn;

        var flags = SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints | SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction;
        copier = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, flags, null);
        copier.BulkCopyTimeout = 180;

        foreach (var f in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsValueType || p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
            copier.ColumnMappings.Add(f.Name, f.Name);

        var tableInfo = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true)[0] as TableAttribute;
        copier.DestinationTableName = $"{tableInfo.Schema ?? "dbo"}.{tableInfo.Name}";
    }

    public Task Connect() { return connection.OpenAsync(); }

    public void Disconnect() { connection.Close(); }

    public Task WriteToServer(ObjectDataReader<T> reader)
    {
        return copier.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (copier != null)
        {
            if(connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) connection.Close();
            if(internalConnection) connection.Dispose();

            copier = null;
            connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `SqlBulkCopier` class? Maybe it's the bottleneck? Back in days I used this code as starting point of doing my own bulk inserter and it worked just fine for millions of records. https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/blob/master/BulkInserter.cs

Comment: Please do not use links to other sites to reference your code in a question here.  Always include the primary code in your question.

Comment: You will also need to include the table, key and index definitions of the table you are inserting into.  Though, that said, you probably need to drop the indexes from your insert table first, and then re-add, or rebuild them after.

Comment: RBarryYoung: dropping and rebuilding the indexes is not an option in this case. 
dlxeon: yeh that's essentially what mine is doing it sets up the SqlBulkCopy class and then consumes it using the ObjecrDataReader of the same generic type.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes i know about linking but in this case I wanted to keep the question as short as possible despite having much to explain, I was also expecting that there might be some call for the classes referenced in my code resulting in this question getting way longer to the point of being unreadable. I figure gists are not something that come and go like the average blog though as they stay around much like SO posts forever.

Comment: The only way to get constant performance out of a bulk copy is to ensure that you import to an empty heap table. All other operations take increasingly more time as the table gets larger, because maintaining the indexes will take more time. This time increases with the total size of the table, not the total size of your batch. If dropping indexes is not an option, look into partitioning; each partition is essentially a separate empty table, which smooths out the import time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I suspected as much ... I just wondered if anyone had any ideas ... partitioning might be the trick here, good call! ... This feels like the answer at least in spirit i just need to dig out a code sample for doing this in C# and cleaning up any mess after. Thanks man :)

Comment: Another option, incidentally, it to just drop the `TableLock` option altogether (so consumers aren't blocked) and set  the total timeout to `0` (that is, allow it to take as long as it takes). Allowing only three minutes for the whole thing seems stingy. The table lock will not measurably improve performance when importing into a non-empty table with indexes anyway.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, might tinker with that ... I ran this on our dev box ... it completed the whole lot ... 132 write calls on SqlBulkCopy in total in about 10 mins ... This might be a non issue after all (for this data at least) ... Must just be my local machine that's particularly slow (probably due to debugging tools and what not)